# How does a looper continue to maintain a thread?

Tags: java, android

while looking through the android documentation I found the following code for looper.loop().

```
public static void loop() {
...
for (;;) {
    Message msg = queue.next(); // might block
    if (msg == null) {
        // No message indicates that the message queue is quitting.
        return;
    }
    ...
    msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);
    ...
}
```

}

Now that doesn't make sense to me because I thought a looper job is to prolong the life of a thread and queue the next message for the handler to handle. However, you can see there is a return and wouldn't that return makes it so that when there are no msg the loop quits hence quitting the thread?

So how exactly does a looper allows thread to continue query and executing task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, you can see there is a return and wouldn't that return makes it so that when there are no msg the loop quits hence quitting the thread?

No. You have to be able to end the thread at some point. What if you want to terminate the owner or indeed cleanly shut down the whole process?

You can infer from this snippet that `queue.next()` will block if there are no more messages but we want to continue monitoring. It'll only return a value once there is another message.

Returning `null` signifies that something else has happened, i.e. the looper is going away for whatever reason.